# MPMoviePlayerController load video from Photo library,play so fast

Tags: ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

//  CameraViewController.h

@interface CameraViewController : UIViewController{

```
UIImagePickerController *_picker;
```

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *player;

- (IBAction)loadImage:(UIButton *)sender;

//  CameraViewController.m

@interface CameraViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *playView;

@end

@implementation CameraViewController

@synthesize imageView = _imageView;

@synthesize player    = _player;

@synthesize playView  = _playView;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

```
[super viewDidLoad];

_picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

{

```
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
```

}

- (IBAction)loadImage:(UIButton *)sender {

  _picker.delegate = self;

  _picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

  NSArray *mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, (NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];

  _picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;

  [self presentViewController:_picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

## pragma mark -ImagePicker Delegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

  UIImage *image = nil;

  NSURL *imageURL = nil;

  imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

  if (imageURL == nil) {

  ```
  image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

  if (image == nil) {

      image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

      _imageView.image = image;

  }

  else {

  }
  ```

  }

  else {

  self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:imageURL];

  ```
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.player];

      self.player.view.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 200.0, 200.0);

      self.player.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

      self.player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

      [self.player prepareToPlay];

      [self.view addSubview:self.player.view];

      [self.player play];
  ```

  }

  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

## pragma mark - User Define

- (void)movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification *)notification {

  MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [notification object];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

  [player.view removeFromSuperview];

}

The movieFinishedCallback:method will be called immediately,so the video can not play completely.

How to resolve it?

Comment: well,could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Apple suggests：

Uses AVPlayer to play videos from the iPod Library, Camera Roll, or via iTunes File Sharing.